# Software to capture video from a device?

Tags: software-rec, video-capture

I recently bought an [EzCap USB video capture device](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003YGJLWU), which works like a regular capture card except through USB.

Anyway, the device works fine, except the software that came with it to capture the signal is very... bloat-ware like. It's filled with ads and makes a stupid program force itself on startup.

I've tried to capture the media through VLC, but there's a severe input delay. Even though I hate this software (ShowBiz DVD 2) the video capture is perfect, and there isn't any delay or lag. Is there anything better than VLC that can capture video through a device?

Preferably something that I can run full-screen. The ShowBiz DVD 2 software plays nicely and records great, but like I said, it forces some stupid program on start up, and the bigger problem is that the capture screen is like, 2 inches across. It's impossible to play a PS2 game on the thing.

Comment: could try [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/). I am unsure if there is any lag/delay though

Comment: @Xantec how do you capture from a device through virtualdub? I tried it but only saw options for opening AVI files...

Comment: quickly searching [Google](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=virtualdub+capture+tutorial&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=573da4ec7e15bdf2) i found [this](http://www.teachers.ash.org.au/dbrown/virtualdub/capture.htm) tutorial. I've never used VirtualDub to capture video myself, so i am afraid my own experience is limited in this respect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [Xantec](https://superuser.com/users/31680/xantec)'s comments, I was able to get VirtualDub working.

To get the EzCap 116 device to play in [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/), you should download the latest version of the program.

Start the program, then:

- Go into `File` > `Capture AVI...`
- If no video plays, go into `Devices` > `WDM 2861 Capture`

  - if that is already selected, then go to `Video` > `Video sources` and select either the Composite or S-Video, depending on what you're using
- If the video is choppy or does not play, try these:

  - Go into `Audio` > untick `Enable audio playback` (having it ticked creates severe frame rate issues)
  - Go into `Video` > `Compression` and change it to something other than "No recompression" (you may have to experiment a little)
  - Go into `Video` > `Capture Filter` and change the settings (Default is NTSC_M, I have luck with NTSC_M_J and others have luck with NTSC_433. If you live elsewhere in the world, you might try some of the PAL options. YMMV)
- For best results when capturing, make sure that you're running the capture in a static, unchanging size; i.e., "Stretch to window" is not ticked nor is "Full Screen". If you want to change the size, you can go into `Video` > `Set custom format`, but VirtualDub seems to set the size at the device's natural output.
- If you want to apply a filter to your video as it plays, go to `Video` > `Filter chain` > `Filter list...` and add your desired filters.
- When capturing, your audio **will** desync. It's a fairly common problem with VirtualDub. Look around for tutorials on how to edit your video to fix this.